# WinSock2 cant connect to simple server

Tags: c, sockets, networking, winsock2

I'm learning networking on windows using C and I get this weird 10038 error

```
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET connect_socket;
printf("Initialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}printf("Initialised.\n");

if (connect_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Could not create socket : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return -1;
}
printf("Socket created.\n");
struct sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(80);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("142.250.184.196");
if (connect(connect_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) != 0)
{
    printf("connect error : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

printf("Connected\n");

return 0;
```

nslookup [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) -> "142.250.184.196"
when trying to run program prints: "
Initialising Winsock...Initialised.
Socket created.
connect error : 10038"

Comment: You need additional parenthesis here: `if ((connect_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)`

Comment: Use two lines.  Stop cramming assignments into `if` statements - it's **bug-prone**.  `connect_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` and then `if ( connect_socket == INVALID_SOCKET ) ...` and you'll never have this problem again.

Comment: What Andrew says.  Beginners write simple code, then they find that they can write 'cool, clever' compound expressions and then, after finally realizing that debugging is a massive PITA, they become skilled developers who write simple code again:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if (connect_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == INVALID_SOCKET) {

Based on the [operator precedence in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) this means

```
connect_socket = (socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

Thus `connect_socket` is not the actual socket but the result of the check if the socket is valid. Assuming that socket creation worked then `connect_socket` will thus be false, i.e. `0`.

Since 0 is not a valid TCP socket `connect` will fail with [error 10038](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2):

> WSAENOTSOCK
> 10038
> Socket operation on nonsocket.
> An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid.

To fix this, first assign to `connect_socket`, then compare with `INVALID_SOCKET`.